# "which" with a little "grep"-like solution?

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards, path

```
# which mkdir
/bin/mkdir
# which mkdi
#
```

How can I get the path of the e.g.: `mkdir`'s binary without knowing the name of the binary file? (command). So that `which mkdi` would output the `/bin/mkdir` too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In zsh:

```
echo $path/mkdi*(N)
```

In other shells, for human consumption:

```
set -f; IFS=:
for x in $PATH; do set +f; ls $x/mkdi* 2>/dev/null; done
```

Comment: @LanceBaynes, this is a better answer than mine.

Comment: Good, but not grep-like.  no regex here.

Comment: @Philomath In ksh, bash and zsh, wildcards are regexps (with an unusual syntax).

Comment: ~something like this

Answer (score 4):

[locate](http://linux.die.net/man/1/locate)

```
locate mkdi
```

---

Update: this will restrict the output to files in the `$PATH`

```
locate mkdi | 
while read filename; do 
  [[ ":$PATH:" == *:$(dirname $filename):* ]] && echo $filename
done
```

Comment: `locate` searches the whole file-system based on a data-base, unlike `which` which searches the files in $PATH as per the current state.

Comment: On my system that returns thousands of files that happen to be in a project folder with that string fragment as part of the path. Not a replacement for `which`.

Comment: A slightly better way in practice is `locate bin/mkdi`. Still, it looks in public parts of the filesystem (or whatever `updatedb` indexes), without considering `$PATH`.

Comment: Note that if you want to search grep-like (regex), you have to pass `-r` or `--regex` to `locate`.  It's still database based, though.

Answer (score 4):

`run-parts` can do exactly that, given the right parameters.   Here is a simple wrapper I wrote around it:

```
#!/bin/bash
# swhich - search the path (like which) but with support for regular expressions
# "swhich '.*ch$' '^wh'" to find all in path ending with 'ch' and all starting with 'wh'
set -f; IFS=:
for all in $PATH
  do
  set +f
  for each in "$@"
    do
    run-parts --list --regex "$each" "$all"
  done
done
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're not sure of the executable you're looking for, you can also query the `man` database with the `apropos` command, for example `apropos dir` will list commands commonly used when working with directories, find the command you need, pass it to `which` as normal.

Comment: IF the executable has a manpage AND you have done `makewhatis` recently.

Answer (score 2):

`compgen` is a BASH builtin that generates completions for a given string. The `-c` switch completes command names in the path:

```
$ compgen -c mkd
mkdirhier
mkdir
mkdiskimage
mkdir
```

*Note: `mkdir` is on here twice because it's in both /bin and /usr/bin on my system.*

Programmable completion is cool. It will let you do things like this:

```
$ shopt -s progcomp; complete -c which # set up progcomp
$ which mkd<ALT-*>
$ which mkdir mkdirhier mkdiskimage
```

...which may be closer to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here's yet another way of getting the binary path (if the prefix is known) by using `printf` and file name globbing in Bash.

```
mywhich() (
  bin="$1"
  PATH="${PATH// /\\ }"  # escape spaces
  #eval 'echo "$PATH"'
  #printf '%s\n' "printf '%s\n' ${PATH//://${bin}* }/${bin}*" | bash -s -f -O nullglob --
  result="$(printf '%s\n' "printf '%s\n' ${PATH//://${bin}* }/${bin}*" | bash -s +f -O nullglob --)"
  [[ -n "$result" ]] && printf '%s\n' "$result" && exit 0 || exit 1
)

mywhich mkdi
```

Answer (score 0):

The following approach lists all full paths to the matched binaries using only Bash builtins:

```
# mywhich version 2
mywhich() ( # using a subshell the parent shell is not affected by set & shopt, ...
  bin="$1"
  set +f
  shopt -s nullglob
  IFS=':' read -a array <<<"$PATH"
  IFS=""
  result="$( printf '%s\n' ${array[@]/%//${bin}*} )"
  [[ -n "$result" ]] && printf '%s\n' "$result" && exit 0 || exit 1
)

mywhich mkdi
```

Answer (score 0):

### Look for man pages

As you are searching commands, instead of matching the names of the command binaries, you could match names of man pages as an alternative; This could make sense because `man` already provides this feature by default:

```
$ man --sections=1,8 --where --all --regex '^mkdi' 
/usr/share/man/man1/mkdir.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mkdirhier.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mkdiskimage.1.gz
```

Using `sed` to extract the command names only:

```
$ man --sections=1,8 --where --all --regex '^mkdi' | \
    sed -r 's/.*\/([^/]+)\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$/\1/'
mkdir
mkdirhier
mkdiskimage
```

And running `which` for the command names too:

```
$ man --sections=1,8 --where --all --regex '^mkdi' | \
    sed -r 's/.*\/([^/]+)\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$/\1/' | xargs which 
/bin/mkdir
/usr/bin/mkdirhier
/usr/bin/mkdiskimage
```

The patterns are regular expressions, so the `^` is added to match only at the beginning of the name.
For a pattern syntax similar to a shell glob, replace `--regex` by `--wildcard`,
like `man ... --wildcard 'mkdi*' | ...`.

As a shell function:

```
whichmatch() {       
    man --sections=1,8 --where --all --regex "$@" |
        sed -r 's/.*\/([^/]+)\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$/\1/' |
        xargs which
}
```

used like:

```
whichmatch '^mkdi'
```

---

For approximate matching of command names, [`whichman`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/whichman.1.html) could be used in place of `man`.